# Проблема с подключением БД

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Ненавижу БД и всё, что с ними связано, но работать как то надо. Пытаюсь подключить БД, выдаёт ошибку. Что делать?

Код:

```
    public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        protected AppContext() : base("DbConnectionString") <------ Это выделяет красным
        {

        }
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
Ошибка  CS1503  Аргумент 1: не удается преобразовать из "string" в "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions".    test2   C:\Users\apost\source\repos\test2\test2\AppContext.cs
```

Comment: Кавычки-то зачем? Ну и значение переменной DbConnectionString - оно должно откуда-то взяться...

Comment: Ну так скажите мне зачем! Я абсолютный нуб. Занимаюсь этим впервые

Comment: Конкретно по MySql смотрите [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-example.html)

Comment: У вас консольное приложение или веб-сайт?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что проблема не с EF а с DI - но выяснится это разумеется, когда поставите правильно вызов базового конструктора правильно. Ибо не принимает там конструктор строку подключения, он ждёт `DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options`

Comment: Модератор, вам корона не жмёт? А что второй мой комментарий не удалили? Он не имеет смысла без первого. В сумме они являются (являлись) ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что правильно вот так:

```
public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options)
   : base(options)
{
}
```

И для меня загадка, что у вас там дальше, потому что есть три варианта для чего вам это понадобилось и два варианта приложения. Но это видимо будет уже совсем другой вопрос.

Ну а пока пусть так что ли будет: в вашем Startup.cs впишите:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(x => x.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionStringName")));
    }
```

И проверьте наличие в csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.17" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: DI не обязателен. Автор же начинающий. В официальной документации (ссылку на которую удалил злобный модер) дан пример кода без лишних сложностей.